# Convert Excel Columns into Rows

Tags: excel

Please take a look at the attached snapshot.

[image: Table]
How to convert the Original Table to the Required Table, in the easiest manner ?

Here, I have shared just a small sample, the real table is quite big having more then 100 rows / symbols and 100 columns / dates.
Therefor it is not possible to manually copy paste the data to change the table format.
The final output table will have just 3 columns "symbol, date and value" arranged according to the dates in ascending order.

Please suggest how to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here it is.
Put Original table in one sheet, say **Sheet1**. Top left cell being **A1** = **Symbol**
Go to another sheet, say **Sheet2**.
In cell **A1** put: **Symbol**
In cell **B1** put: **Date**
in cell **C1** put: **Value**

Go to cell **A2** and put this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & 2+MOD(ROW()-2; X);TRUE)
```

Go to cell **B2** and put this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!R1C" & 2+ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-2)/X;0);FALSE)
```

Go to cell **C2** and put this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!R" &2+MOD(ROW()-2; X)&"C" & 2+ROUNDDOWN((ROW()-2)/X;0);FALSE)
```

In all formulas above, replace **X** with the number of Symbols you got. In your original table there are 4.
**Now fill down as needed**
Note: If functions don't work, use comma(***,***) instead of semicolon(***;***).

Comment: That's right, Transpose was not enough for this question. Yours solves it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying. I did exactly as you told, but there seems to be an issue with the formula. It is showing some error in the formula where you have typed <(ROW()-2;>. I have uploaded the example excel file here - http://d-h.st/JhH

Comment: you forgot to replace **X** in first formula =INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & 2+MOD(ROW()-2; 4);TRUE). Remember, you have to put the actual number of Symbols you got, for the actual table...

Comment: I am sorry, I somehow missed to replace the X in the first formula earlier. But even after making this change, the formula does not works. It has some error in the <(ROW()-2;> part. Did this formula work correctly on your computer ? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it works for me... you have to make another change then... I use semicolons to separate parameters in functions. Maybe your settings is to use commas. look at answer... in formulas, where you see **( ; )** replace with **( , )**

Comment: Superb. That is brilliant, works perfectly. I apologize for not being able to make the correct changes in the formula provided by you earlier. After making those 2 changes in all the required places, the formulas works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help.